# Angular redirects to weird url string

Tags: angular

I have `[AuthGuard]` for `/profile/personal-data` which watching if the user has logged or not . And after `login()` I do `this.router.navigates['profile/persnal-data']` and it works correct. But when I'm not logged in and try to put in browser `/profile/person` then app redirects me to `?path=%2Fprofile%2Fpersonal-data`. I don't know what am I doing wrong ?

**route.config**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProfileComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'personal-data', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'personal-data', component: PersonalDataComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    ]
  }

];
```

**Gurard.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { AuthentificationService } from '../services/authentification.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private authentificationService: AuthentificationService,
  ) { }

  isEmpty(obj): boolean {
    for (const prop in obj) {
      if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return JSON.stringify(obj) === JSON.stringify({});
  }

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      if (
        localStorage.getItem('access-token-1cb-portal') != null &&
        localStorage.getItem('expires-at-access-1cb-portal') != null &&
        localStorage.getItem('refresh-token-1cb-portal') != null &&
        localStorage.getItem('expires-at-refresh-1cb-portal') != null
      ) {
        observer.next(true);
        observer.complete();
        return;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/'], {
          queryParams: {
            path: state.url
          }
        });
        observer.next(false);
        observer.complete();
        return;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**UPD 1**

I have updated my Guard to simple

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request);
  }
```

It still redirect's me to main page with strange url `http://localhost:4200/?path=%2Fprofile%2Fpersonal-data` but when I remove `canActivate: [AuthGuard]` from my `route.config` for `profile` route ,and it workes and redirect to the right page. What is going wrong , why the guard make huge sense for this behaviour ?

Comment: Try `this.router.navigates['/profile','persnal-data']`

Comment: What is the desired behaviour?

Comment: redirect is working well, the desired result is : when I manually put /profile/personal-data the angular will not redirecting me to main page

Comment: the main question in which cases angular converts url to ```path=%2Fprofile%2Fpersonal-data```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guyes , it was my stupid mistake
my Guard was redirecting to weird string due to code that I have written in my guard a long time ago . Sorry I have missed this code

```
return Observable.create(observer => {
      if (
        localStorage.getItem('access-token-1cb-portal') != null &&
        localStorage.getItem('expires-at-access-1cb-portal') != null &&
        localStorage.getItem('refresh-token-1cb-portal') != null &&
        localStorage.getItem('expires-at-refresh-1cb-portal') != null
      ) {
        observer.next(true);
        observer.complete();
        return;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate(['/'], {
          queryParams: {
            path: state.url // that is the reason
          }
        });
        observer.next(false);
        observer.complete();
        return;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the pathMatch: 'full' (in the routes constant) prevents you to go to /profile/personal-data when typing /profile.person. Try adding
{ path: "**", redirectTo: "personal-data" } at the bottom.

Comment: I have tried , but it didnt help. Just when I remove canActivate: [AuthGuard] it works . But my GUard do not do anything special